# Opengl: Print with glDrawElements

Tags: opengl

Umm.. I wrote this code to print mesh (var m), and it's running well

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
for (unsigned i : m.vtIndex)
{
    const aiVector3D *pv = &m.pMesh->mVertices[i];
    const aiVector3D *pvn = &m.pMesh->mNormals[i];
    glNormal3fv((const GLfloat *)pvn);
    glVertex3fv((const GLfloat *)pv);
}
glEnd();
```

And here is other one

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, m.pMesh->mVertices);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, m.pMesh->mNormals);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m.vtIndex.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &m.vtIndex[0]);
```

But second one occured access violation
Could you give me an opinion?

Comment: @RogerRowland: That's not correct. **glDrawElements expects the number of vertices** (you're supposed to be able to change the *mode* keeping the rest of the parameters unchanged). It'd rather assume, that `m.vtIndex.size()` doesn't return the number of elements in the array, but the size in bytes, which is not what you want here.

Comment: @datenwolf: Err, `glDrawElements (...)` expects the number of elements... you can draw 1 vertex as many times as you want if you use the same index over and over.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Yes, I know that. What I meant was not the number of vertices in the attribute buffers, but the number of vertices glDrawElements shall process. Even if it's the same vertex N times over, OpenGL has to process N vertices.

Answer (score 1):

You are using deprecated OpenGL in this example and using client memory to store vertex data. In deprecated OpenGL, you need to enable the appropriate client states:

```
glEnableClientState (GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState (GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
```

If you add this to your code before your draw call, it ought to fix your crash.

You can safely leave `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY` enabled for the entire time your program runs, but you may need to enable/disable other arrays such as `GL_NORMAL_ARRAY` depending on which vertex pointers your meshes actually use.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out.

```
glEnableClientState(GL_INDEX_ARRAY); // Oops!!
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
```

haha....